# TDengine Question about stopping a TDengine query

Tags: database, tdengine

I was running queries through TDengine's python connectors and encountered some queries that runs over 10 minutes. Is there a way to stop these queries?
Through show queries, I can see the running query, but I cannot execute kill queries to terminate these queries.

```
taos> show queries;
   query_id       |           user           |        ip:port         |        qhandle         |      created_time       |         time          |              sql               |
=======================================================================================================================================================================================
 3:3                  | root                     | 52.151.27.227:55534    | 0x1                    | 2021-07-31 12:08:09.051 |               8843558 | select min(col0) , max(col1... |
Query OK, 1 row(s) in set (0.027953s)

taos> kill queries;

DB error: syntax error near "queries;" (0.000139s)
taos>
```

Am I using the correct command? Is it possible to stop a query for TDengine like other databases?

Thanks in advance, any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
kill query 3:3;
```

KILL QUERY ;

https://www.taosdata.com/en/documentation/administrator